# How to change the dropdown hover color react Material-UI Select

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I need to change my dropdown hover to green. I tried inline CSS and `makeStyle()`, But non of these are not working for me. I have no idea to change this hover color. If anyone can help me with this, I really appreciate it.

[image]

I need to change this hover color into green.
This is my code:-

```
                        <Select
                            className={dropDowStyle.select}
                            style={{
                                borderRadius: '8px', marginLeft: '-150px',
                                width: '163px', height: '45px', fontSize: '15px',
                                backgroundColor: "transparent",borderColor:primaryColor + "88"
                            }}
                            sx={{width: 163}}
                            // defaultValue=""
                            input={<OutlinedInput style={{borderColor: primaryColor + "88",}}/>}
                            displayEmpty
                            value={city}
                            renderValue={(value) => {
                                return (
                                    <Box sx={{display: "flex", gap: 2.5}}>
                                        <SvgIcon style={{fontSize: '20px'}}>
                                            <LocationOnIcon/>
                                        </SvgIcon>
                                        {renderLocation && value}
                                    </Box>
                                );
                            }}
                            onChange={cityValueHandler}
                        >

                            {shopLocation.map((option) => (
                                <MenuItem key={option.gg} value={option.gg}>
                                    {option.gg}
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Select>
```

Comment: shoot. Just to clarify, do you want the border color of the input or the color of the dropdown list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The container of the menu list is a `Paper` which is part of the `Menu` (the dropdown of the `Select`). You can target the props of the nested component like below. See [here](https://mui.com/api/menu/#css) for the list of `Menu` classNames. Also have a look at all [classNames](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#state-classes) for the component states.

```
<Select
  // to override the border color of the Select input
  sx={{
    "&:hover": {
      "&& fieldset": {
        border: "3px solid green"
      }
    }
  }}
  // to override the color of the dropdown container
  MenuProps={{
    PaperProps: {
      sx: {
        "& .MuiMenuItem-root.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "yellow"
        },
        "& .MuiMenuItem-root:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "pink"
        },
        "& .MuiMenuItem-root.Mui-selected:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inputProps` of `Select` and set the `sx` prop like this:

```
    <Select
      inputProps={{
        sx: {
          "&.MuiOutlinedInput-input:hover": {
            border: "2px solid green"
          }
        }
      }}
    >
```

[image: Edit 69436218/how-to-change-dropdown-hover-color-react-material-ui-select (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the element you want to apply hover CSS.
https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles
For example find MuiSlider-thumb in the elements and try to apply on, discard the hash value in front

```
.MuiSlider-thumb:hover {
 color:green;
}
```

or background to green.

Be careful as this might override all of the selects in your code base, so it might not be the best solution.